# Dynamic functions for dynamic generated div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, append

```
success: function (html) {
    $("#Concretisering").append('<li><input type="text"  /></li>');
}
```

I have a function like this, it works but...
In another function I generate some divs, so I have like:

- Concretisering
- Concretisering1
- Concretisering2
- ...

My question is, how can I manipulate this bit of code $("#Concretisering") so every div has the .append function?

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you should do smth like this `$('div').each(function() { this.append('...'); }`

Comment: @netme- there may be many dive all over the page

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, thanks for hint, but it's written "every div". Anyway, I've added your hint to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ids ...provide your divs class of 'Concretisering'. Then it would become:

```
 $(".Concretisering:not(:has(li))").append('<li><input type="text"  /></li>');
```

Comment: The problem now is, every element with class Concretisering will be rewarded with a textbox. The situation must me like, when a div is made, you can add a textbox to that div, only that div

Comment: can u please create a fiddle having code to create the divs as u r using it?

Comment: made an edit to add li only to those div which does not have it already

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do what you are asking for which will satisfy various conditions.Unless you create simplified fiddle which emulates your problem ..it will be very hard to fix it